# How to save a Sales Order in NetSuite with a name including the document number instead of the transaction number (internal ID of the transaction)?

Tags: javascript, pdf, netsuite

Have a problem with saving SO to my computer from NetSuite with the name that I need. Right now I'm using the print button then changing it to "Save as PDF" and setting the name to what I need. Is there a way to change the name of that PDF file so it will automatically populate the name that I need "Sales order #"Document number" ( like "SalesOrder_2345.pdf") instead of "Sales Order #Transaction number"("SalesOrder_232435464758593.pdf")?

I'm looking into Java scripts, never worked with them before.

Maybe something like this?

```
`/**
* @NSscriptType UserEventScript
* @NApiVersion 2.0
*/
define(function (){
return {
entrypoint : function setPDFName(){
var pdfFileName = rec.getValue({fieldid: 'record.title'});
var soNumberValue = rec.getValue({fieldid: 'record.tranid'}); 
var pdfResult = renderer.renderAsPdf()
pdfResult.name = pdfFileName + ' ' + soNumberValue + '.pdf'
}
}
});`
```

Would appreciate any help on that!!